# How to filter data of duplicates in SQL Server result on condition

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I have a requirement like with below table to remove duplicates base don signTf flag there by

[image]

So now I want to filter this combination such that the Id row should be unique and while showing we should consider 0 in case if id have both 1 and 0

Example in above

- `ID` `5` has both `Signed_flag` of `0` and `1` so we shall take only `5` with `0`
- `ID` `4` has both `1`, so show `1`

I tried my best but was not able to get this. Is anyone can help me with SQL Server query to get this?

Comment: I think you might have stroked out here: *"base don signTf flag there by"* Can you clarify what you meant?

Comment: What's your expect result? I am not sure your logic

Comment: `SELECT ID, MIN(Signed_Flag) as Signed_Flag FROM yourtable GROUP BY ID;` I *think* might be what you are after, although it's difficult to tell. If that isn't it, please include your desired/expected results so we can understand better.

Comment: SELECT ID, MIN(Signed_Flag) as Signed_Flag FROM yourtable GROUP BY ID This worked thank you :)

Comment: Ok, your first sentence sounds like you don't want a select only, but really delete the selected data. So thank you for your feedback that this solves your issue.